# XPath select ancestor attribute of some child

Tags: xpath

**Given**

```
<catalogue>
  <produits>
    <produit id="pdt1" libelle="produit 1" cat="PDT">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="123456">
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl">
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr">
      </metas>
    </produit>
    <produit id="pdt2" libelle="produit 2" cat="PDT">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="abcdef">
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl">
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr">
      </metas>
    </produit>
    <produit id="pdt3" libelle="produit 3" cat="PDT">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="123456">
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl">
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr">
      </metas>
    </produit>
  </produits>
</catalogue>

<catalogue>
  <produits>
    <produit id="pdt1" libelle="produit 1" cat="PDT">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="123456">
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl">
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr">
      </metas>
    </produit>
    <produit id="pdt2" libelle="produit 2" cat="PDT">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="abcdef">
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl">
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr">
      </metas>
    </produit>
    <produit id="pdt3" libelle="produit 3" cat="PDT">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="123456">
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl">
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr">
      </metas>
    </produit>
  </produits>
</catalogue>
```

**Required:** Find the values of id if their sub-node meta contains 123456.

**My attempt:**

I can access meta elements using `//meta[@* = "123456"]` I need to select ancestors ids.

**source:** http://practicalsqa.net/beginning-brainteaser-querying-subchildren/

**UPDATE**
Thanks @CiaPan for correcting 2 errors in the above XML, the correct one is:

```
  <data>
   <catalogue>
      <produits>
         <produit id="pdt1" libelle="produit 1" cat="PDT">
            <metas date="2015.07.24">
               <meta code="123456" value="123456" />
               <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl" />
               <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr" />
            </metas>
         </produit>
         <produit id="pdt2" libelle="produit 2" cat="PDT">
            <metas date="2015.07.24">
               <meta code="123456" value="abcdef" />
               <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl" />
               <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr" />
            </metas>
         </produit>
         <produit id="pdt3" libelle="produit 3" cat="PDT">
            <metas date="2015.07.24">
               <meta code="123456" value="123456" />
               <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl" />
               <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr" />
            </metas>
         </produit>
      </produits>
   </catalogue>
   <catalogue>
      <produits>
         <produit id="pdt1" libelle="produit 1" cat="PDT">
            <metas date="2015.07.24">
               <meta code="123456" value="123456" />
               <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl" />
               <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr" />
            </metas>
         </produit>
         <produit id="pdt2" libelle="produit 2" cat="PDT">
            <metas date="2015.07.24">
               <meta code="123456" value="abcdef" />
               <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl" />
               <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr" />
            </metas>
         </produit>
         <produit id="pdt3" libelle="produit 3" cat="PDT">
            <metas date="2015.07.24">
               <meta code="123456" value="123456" />
               <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl" />
               <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr" />
            </metas>
         </produit>
      </produits>
   </catalogue>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to use complex Xpath Axises, you could select an item which has a specific child by this logic:

```
item[.//someShild]
```

so required xpath is:

```
//produit[.//meta[@value=123456]]/@id
```

or you can select all items with specific meta by `//produit[.//meta[@value=123456]]` and get ids with another tool

Answer (score 1):

Find all appropriate `meta` elements, then look for their ancestors.

If you're interested in a given value in specified two attributes:

```
/descendant::meta[ (@code, @value)="123456"]/ancestor::*/@id
```

If the value may be found in *any* attribute of `meta` element:

```
distinct-nodes( /descendant::meta[ @* = "123456"]/ancestor::*)/@id
```

You can also work the other way: scan all elements with `id` attributes, test their `meta` descendant elements and return `id` attributes for those meeting criteria:

```
/descendant::*[ @id and descendant::meta[ @* = "123456"]]/@id
```

Comment: Thank you, but on trying your solutions found that still not accepted in  http://practicalsqa.net/beginning-brainteaser-querying-subchildren/

Comment: @AmrLotfy Well. it worked for me at https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html However, I had to **fix your XML syntax** first...

Comment: I can't see any missing `>` as it mentions at  freeformatter.com, I already posted the source in question, however I tried same xml another site (https://www.xmlvalidation.com) and it also complains from line 8, how did you fix it ?

Comment: @AmrLotfy Error 1) there seem to be two top-level (root) elements `<catalogue>` – either remove one of them or enclose them both in another, single root element, say `<data> ... </data>`. Error 2) is in line 5, but remains undetected until line 8, and it is lack of closing tag to `<meta>` elements – add a slash to each to transform opening tag `<meta code="123456" value="123456">` into a closed tag `<meta code="123456" value="123456"/>`.

Comment: You are right, Posted XML has errors, I will recheck and fix as needed, Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: Possible also to use: `//meta[ @*="123456"]/ancestor::*/@id`